# Receive gifts fom friends while in my application

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

i am trying to implement a "gifting" mechanic in my game. I looked at [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/requests/) and i am able to send requests to friends (even with frictionless dialogs and so on)

My friends are able to receive the requests but the only described way to handle the request is to make them click on the notification in the native FB app and then handle it in my app via the `application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url`
That looks very inconvinient to me!

What if 2 friends sent me a request? Do i have to click them both?
What if I am in the app already? Do i have to go to the FB app click on the notification that brings me back to my app?

So the question is: Is there a way to see all the received requests for my app and handle them accordingly while I am in my app?

Comment: ok i did a bit more research: 
once i send a request it shows up in the App Center under requests. I can send a lot of requests and they all stack up there.
Once i click one accept it should redirect me to my app and i can extract the request from the url. but how do i list all the pending requests in my app like the example [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/requests/#scenarios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clear things:
I got a little confused about the notifications you get when receiving an apprequest and the actual requests. The requests can be viewed and managed via the graph path `/me/apprequests` 
You can view and accept them in your app in an inbox-like way for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your description but I'll give it a shot.

I guess you're trying to send 'gifts' to other users in your app. Do you have some sort of notification mechanism in your app? Similar to how I view a notification when someone posts to my wall on facebook. Once I tap the notification icon and see it, the notification array or whatever it is, is empty. So if I was to go to facebook's site, I wouldn't see any pending gifts.

I would create some sort of notification class that temporarily holds gifts so you can move in and not viewed/not viewed gifts.

Comment: yeah, i would make a "gift inbox" in my app. but i want it to be filled when im in the app so i dont have to go to facebook every time and click on the notification to receive the gift